# disable enable button on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to enable button when there is some value in text box

this is working fine all most but for one value it will fail

like is enter  1 in text box

http://jsfiddle.net/akash4pj/YhQN4/

js

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#textbx").keypress(function(){
 if ($("#textbx").val().length > 0) {
      $("#btn").removeAttr('disabled');

   }
});

 $("#textbx").blur(function(){
    if ($("#textbx").val().length ==0) {
      $("#btn").attr('disabled','disabled');

   }
  });

});
</script>
```

html code

```
 <input id="textbx" type="text" /><button id="btn" disabled="disabled">go</button>
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/D2fe9/...?

Comment: could please create one js fiddle for better idea of your.. also I am unable to understand your description. for this `like is enter 1 in text box`

Comment: I think that you can delete the blur event and do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dzTkf/

Comment: thanks guys a got a lot of answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `keyup` instead of `keypress`, like this:

```
$("#textbx").blur(function () {
    if ($("#textbx").val().replace(/\s{1,}/g, "").length == 0) {
        $("#btn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Also, I've added `.replace(/\s{1,}/g, "")` in the code as well. This ensures (indirectly) that if the user only types spaces, the button will still be disabled when the text input is blurred.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wEw4p/2/).

Answer (score 2):

The `keypress` event occurs before the browser processes the key, i.e. before the character is appended to the input value, so when the first key is pressed, the textbox is still empty when your functions checks the value length.

The `keyup` event occurs after the browser has appended the character to the input, so if you trigger on `keyup` instead of `keypress` your code should function the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$("#textbx").on('keyup blur', function() {
    $("#btn").prop('disabled', $.trim(this.value).length === 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers you should use keyup, but you don't need to listen for blur as well:

```
 $("#textbx").keyup(function(){   
    if ($("#textbx").val().trim().length > 0) {
      $("#btn").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else
      $("#btn").attr('disabled','disabled');
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9k5G/)

Comment: That's not what OP wants